# read and write files open() read()

Tags: c, file, byte

i need  to make a program that read a file(arg[1]) and show it content but, with a specific number of bytes[arg2]. If no bytes are specified whole file will be printed.

```
void read(char *arg[]){
        int fh;
        char buffer[100];
        int rd;

        fh = open(arg[1],O_RDONLY);
        printf ("Printing %s\n",arg[1]);
        while (rd = read(fh,buffer,100)) {
                buffer[rd] = '\0';
                printf("%s",buffer);
                }
        }
```

I need to use open(),read() at least.
Can someone help me?

Comment: what is arg2? maximum bytes you want to read from a file?

Comment: and.. do you mean all files by Whole file? which is specified in arg1.?

Comment: in arg[1] you specified the name of a file and arg2 is the bytes to read, yes . yes i mean whole file, sorry for my english.

Comment: ok, i am still confused. you already are reading from the file. so what is remain now? the constrain to limit only arg[2] bytes from the file?

Comment: exactly, how can i do that?

Comment: You appear to be working with a text file since you use `printf("%s",buffer);` but `read` is better used for binary data. Typically with a text file you don't know how long each line/string will be, and it is usual to use `fgets`. Function `read` does not stop at the end of a text line (unless reaching EOF).

Comment: You don't use `arg[2]` in the function. A better style would be for `main` to check the number of arguments, extract the integer value from `argv[2]`, and pass the file name and the number of bytes as two arguments to a function called such as `myread(char *filename, unsigned int count)`.

Comment: Is `c` smart enough to call the correct `read`?  `read(fd, char*, int)` from the `c` library and `read(char*)` that you have defined may collide.  I'm surprised that this even compiles.

Comment: @KevinDTimm this is the problem with a code snippet without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I deleted my previous comment *"You have named your function `void read()` which clearly conflicts with the library function `int read()` which your function is calling."* because we don't know if `#include <io.h>` is present, or if the compiler thinks this is recursion ;)

Comment: Actually, the real name of the fuction is different in my program, i just changed here .

Comment: Oh FFS. Post the real, actual, code that you use: not "something like my code". Time waster.

Comment: @WeatherVane i dont use because i didnt know how to use, thats why i ask how can i implement. I will try with fgets, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Good, please look up example usage, and remember that `fgets` reads any terminating newline, unless a) there isn't one (perhaps the last line in a text file), or b) the buffer size was hit.

Comment: time waster? if i post the real actual code that i use i have to post the 800 lines of my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few observation about the program which you wrote,

1. `void read(char *arg[])`  here from main() function you are just passing the file name then whats the need of catching file name with `array of char pointer`, catching with single char pointer is sufficient. So modify it like `void read(char *arg)`
2. `fh = open(arg[1], O_RDONLY);` open() is system call, whether its able to open the file or not,catch the return value & try to print error message using `perror()`. So modify its like

```
fh = open(arg[1], O_RDONLY);
if (fh == -1) {  
    perror("open");
    return;
}
```

3. `while (rd = read(fh,buffer,100)) { //some code }` why rotating loop ? you can read entire data of file at a time, for that use `stat()` system call and find the size of file and then create dynamic array equivalent to file size and then read whole/particular data using `read()` system call.

So first go through man pages of `open()`, `read()`, `stat()` system calls.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int my_read(char *fname) {
    int fh, n;
    struct stat v;

    /*
     * Don't use static array because we don't know how much data is there
     * in file, create it dynamically.
     * char buffer[100];
     */
    char *p;

    fh = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
    if (fh == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    /* first find the size of file .. use stat() system call */
    stat(fname, &v);

    /* create dynamic array equal to file size */
    p = malloc(v.st_size * sizeof(char));

    printf("enter no of bytes you want to read: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n <= 0)
        return 2;

    /* read data from file and copy into dynamic array and print */
    if (read(fh, p, n) == -1) {
        perror("read");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("data read from %s:\n", fname);
    printf("%s\n", p);

    if (close(fh) < 0) {
        perror("c1");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char f_name[100];

    printf("enter the file name: ");
    scanf("%s", f_name);
    return my_read(f_name);
}
```

Comment: Should be `int fd`, not `int fh`

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(char* buff, int size)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size ; i++)
  {
    printf("%c",buff[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE * pFile;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;

    pFile = open ( argv[1] , O_RDONLY );
    if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}
    if(argv[2])
    {
      lSize = argv[2];
    }
    else
    {
      fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
      lSize = ftell (pFile);
      rewind (pFile);
    }

    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}
    result = read (pFile,buffer,lSize);
    if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}
    print(buffer,lSize);


    fclose (pFile);
    free (buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can’t use fopen

Comment: Fixed it for you

Comment: Thanks for your help but i used the code of another answer. I cant give upvote bcz i have less than 15 rep.

Comment: There is a mixup with a previous fopen version: `if (pFile==NULL)`. 0 is a valid fd and open returns -1 on failure. There are many follow up errors....